# Get CSS selector of all matching items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I want to get CSS selector of jQuery items set.

By jQuery items set in this case I mean jQuery set created basing on some css selector and extended by some jQuery functions like `.children` etc like `$(".basic-selector").children();`

It's easy to get for simple scenario like direct selection:

```
$("div.someclaass").selector //works ok - gives div.someclass
```

But I also need to get css selector for more complex scenarios (and here jQuery is not returning valid css selector)

```
$("div.someclass").children("p").selector //schould give div.someclass > p
```

And for more comples scenarios like

```
$("ul, ol").children("li").selector //should give ul > li, ol >li
```

Is it possible?

Requirements:

- It must be valid css selector
- I cant change js code of creating sets
- It should work for all this kind of jQuery functions that can have
  css selector - like `children`, `find`, `next`, `nextAll`, `.filter` (with css param) etc.

There are some functions like `.prev` or `.parent` that will not have css selector - I'm aware of that.

Why do I need that? - I've got my [plugin](http://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize). It takes some jQuery set that was created basing on selector and executes some function on those items. But also - function needs to be executed in the future on new items added later that **would match the set if they would exisit in the time of set creation code execution**. For good understanding please check plugin page.

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear. What do you mean by jQuery items set?

Comment: Just wondering, why would you need that?

Comment: once you start chaining methods there is no built in way to do this. What would your use case be? You can compile a selector by following `parents()` back up the tree

Comment: This really looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271659).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I've tried to point out X problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `.selector` property is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/selector) and can only be used when the jQuery element set was created by passing a selector string directly. As you have seen, `.selector` stops representing a valid selector altogether once you start chaining traversal or filtering methods from the original set. Judging from the sort of values that `.selector` can have it would seem that it was simply not intended for anything other than internal use.

But the real problem here is that not all element sets can be represented with a valid CSS selector (not without enumerating all possible `:nth-child()` permutations anyway), not the least of which is because many of jQuery's non-standard selectors have no standard equivalents. Even if you limit yourself to standard selectors and traversal methods that can be represented with a selector, if the *original* element set was obtained through some other means, or if it was obtained normally and then tampered with, you won't be able to detect this, not even using `.selector` which as I mentioned is deprecated anyway.

If you *really* need a selector string to match your selection, the easiest way is to just write it manually and store it in a separate variable.

Comment: @Adam: if you take the advice from the `.selector` help page linked in this answer, you could rewrite your plugin's API to something like `$(document).initialize("div.foo", initFn);` and you could even make it work with a filter function rather than a selector (but beware of performance issues in this case).